# Getting IDs based on multiple string criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Following data structure:

```
ID   CRIT1    CRIT2
1    L        M
2    H        M
3    H        H
```

I would like to get the IDs with Crit1= H and Crit2=H.
In a second sheet I want to build a table with the IDs which satisfy my criteria. So in this case only `3`.

I tried with INDEX/MATCH and COUNTIF.

However, so far no useful solution based on strings and ranges.

Comment: Could you just create a 4th column that has "=IF(AND(B2="H",C2="H"),TRUE,FALSE)" then filter that column for TRUE values?

Comment: Are the ID's all different or can you get duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a PivotTable without Totals or Subtotals, in Tabular Form, all three columns as ROWS and filtered to select `H` for each of `CRIT1` and `CRIT2`:

[image: SO33418793 example]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula solution That will create your table without any blanks.

This assumes your source data are in Sheet1. Edit as necessary.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$9999,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!B$2:B$9999="H")*(Sheet1!C$2:C$9999="H"),ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$9999),9E+99),ROW(1:1))-1),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now copy downard as far as needed.

Note: adjust the 9999s to a row number suitable to your situation.

Comment: I think this is close, however it returns all IDs see post below

Comment: It works. I just tested it again. It returns the ID only when both criteria are "h".

Comment: Here's a file with your formula. For me it's not working  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2s5Zdqufgk4Q1hUdGZlVkhaWTA

Comment: @heyhey33 I see there was a typo. It's fixed now. See the updated answer.

Comment: sorry, not working, see https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2s5Zdqufgk4cnRzVFBYS1NkdFk

Comment: This will be faster if I post your workbook:  http://www.excelhero.com/samples/array_test2_excelhero.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Without macros you can only copy the single cells if the criteria are satisfied, and don't copy them if not. Paste this formula in A2, then copy it to right (other columns), and to bottom (other rows):

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!$B2="H";Sheet1!$C2="H");Sheet1!A2;"")
```

Comment: And what about all of the blanks that will be produced? Not a very good table, as OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the pivot table does work yes, however I want to plot a graph which seems to be impossible with pivot data model

[image]

Comment: thank you, however I can't create charts based on that solution

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the formula solution I don't think it works.
[image]

It will give me all IDs with either crit1=h or crit2=h

Comment: It works. I just tested it again. It returns the ID only when both criteria are "h".

Comment: can you share an excel file?